# Pandas dataframe compare columns with one value and get this row and previous row into another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
>>> df
   A    B
0  1   56
1  2   75
2  3  102
3  4   15
4  5   19
5  6  116
```

I want to create another dataframe with `B>100` and also store its previous row. It should look like this:

```
>>> df1
   A    B
1  2   75
2  3  102
4  5   19
5  6  116
```

What is the best way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with 2 conditions chained by `|` for bitwise `OR`, second with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), also for cpmpare is used [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html):

```
df1 = df[df.B.gt(100) | df.B.shift(-1).gt(100)]
```

Alternative:

```
df1 = df[(df.B>100) | (df.B.shift(-1)>100)]
```

---

```
print (df1)
   A    B
1  2   75
2  3  102
4  5   19
5  6  116
```